# Access samba by host name

Tags: networking, server, samba

I have set up Samba on Ubuntu Server. Everything works fine, but I can access the dir only by providing ip address: `smb://192.168.1.2/public` but not the host name `smb://myhost/public`.

```
user@host$: cat /etc/hostname
myhost.org
```

What do I need to set up to see this from other machines without providing IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using static IP in your LAN, you can add the following to your /etc/hosts file

```
192.168.1.2    myhost.org
```

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing you have no DNS server in your network. In that case the easiest method is to add a line in the hosts file on your client:

```
192.168.1.2 myhost
```

On Linux this file is in `/etc/hosts`, on Windows it resides in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Don't remove existing lines from the file, just add this line.